# Non-deterministic behavior of Grep in conjunction with More

Tags: windows-7, windows, grep, more

What would you expect to happen after this:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,100) do @more some.bbl | grep a | md5sum
```

Most probably, **not** this:

```
ec3ecb76408d4225ff23a25d0596e00f *-
13cfd899b90b9cd7aedb406a785e8eac *-
737e8898a65657f1a2ce8012ff1ffe82 *-
d4095243e56a7da3b31a352423a5417a *-
319db7810e677414ca1609238bdeba6f *-
31e626a8ce0732fda1fa7499c8b13dfa *-
006fe390f923d50348d65d0bbefa64d8 *-
77708f62cb2d61a45788a656d0979aee *-
cda10a9ab71c2bce4df069c479241349 *-
b01b71dc7dca11808ca989c4985513ca *-
c22a6f8b1cac9a93c4fe10b07a9f483a *-
0b04f4b24f3f183270eb7414f4f86e3d *-
5a2f8b8ad482ae8f70b7ce3384a7c9e2 *-
beccdbe737b48c02b48c4524cd89eede *-
a16fec5238cfe8dfff6b403ff943a8ca *-
ec0cd2edc0009abd14119915a8b563f4 *-
1e78f0012ca09aeade169f815415da40 *-
...
```

I was worried, too, so I ran a couple of sanity checks:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,100) do @more some.bbl | md5sum
```

yields 100 times

```
ace4f37f3a1433e29696a535c0b79f2c *-
```

Same for

```
for /l %i in (1,1,100) do @grep a some.bbl | md5sum
```

and

```
d8753d755025a1119cd2910c6f5cb0de *-
```

So `more`, `grep` and `md5sum` work fine by themselves. Also, the pipe before `md5sum` is not a problem, since

```
for /l %i in (1,1,100) do @more some.bbl | grep a > out%i
md5sum out*
```

confirms the issue. `fc`ing the outputs, I find no difference. `diff`ing them revels invisible differences, confirmed by a hex editor to be differences in line endings in seemingly random places (and different from file to file).

The issue is still seen, but less often so, in this example:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,100) do @more some.bbl | grep "[a-z]" | md5sum
```

yielding

```
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
ef23817185d41987c11cb1fc4371bb76 *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
e398e63b60cee3e271967f01350068f1 *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
b135bcfe0bcfb7f1c43fe1905164c31e *-
...
```

Now I am running out of ideas what the reason could be. I would not care about this much if I did not lose any valid lines in cases like this:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,100) do @more "some.bbl" | grep "\}$" | wc -l
```

This gives

```
249
249
249
248
255
253
252
248
251
...
```

To reproduce similar issues, you can use this file

```
for /l %i in (1,1,200) do @echo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{Something1999a}>> some.bbl
```

Some more information

```
C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

C:\>more /h

Displays output one screen at a time.

MORE [/E [/C] [/P] [/S] [/Tn] [+n]] < [drive:][path]filename
...

C:\>grep --ver

GNU grep 2.6.3

Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

C:\>md5sum --ver

md5sum (GNU coreutils) 8.15
Packaged by Cygwin (8.15-1)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later     <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Ulrich Drepper, Scott Miller, and David Madore.
```

Why is this happening?

**Update:** The problem also goes away by replacing `more` by this `cat`:

```
C:\>cat --ver

cat (GNU coreutils) 8.15
Packaged by Cygwin (8.15-1)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Torbjörn Granlund and Richard M. Stallman.
```

Comment: Why are you using more in this way and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't recall why I initially used `more`. I did notice, though, that in some cases `more | grep` is faster than `grep`. Anyway, isn't it completely irrelevant why I am using `more` (and not `cat`, or `grep`, or whatever) with respect to my question, WHY the combination of command-line tools behaves in a non-deterministic way?

Comment: I think it's relevant because more is not intended to be used in this way. My guess is because you are using more in a way it is not designed to function it is forking or returning at the wrong time, or mis-detecting your terminal parameters because there is no terminal. I wouldn't be surprised at a program behaving non-deterministically when it's documented behaviour is "undefined"

Comment: Oh. So you think the fact that `more` expects terminal input at the end of a screen (when output is not redirected) might interfere with the output? And the apparent randomness basically results from the position on a virtual terminal window? This might actually make sense.